# How do you call a button in another sheet using another button in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button in Sheet1 and I want to activate it using button (form control) in Sheet2.

I have written on Module1 (almost same code with command button in Sheet1)

```
Function DataUpdate()
If (validateVer() = False) Then
    Exit Function
End If

Dim AsCn, AsRs, SQL
Dim x, y, WDATE, NGQTY, FAQTY, RWQTY, RNQTY, TotalCell, TotalCellx
Dim FA_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)
Dim RW_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)
Dim RN_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)
Dim NG_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)


'Sheet => Table
Sheet1.Range("C2:GS2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
FA_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A2:GS2")
Sheet1.Range("C4:GS4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
RW_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A4:GS4")
Sheet1.Range("C5:GS5").Select
Selection.ClearContents
RN_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A5:GS5")
Sheet1.Range("A9:GS208").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheet1.Range("C9").Select
NG_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A8:GS208")
```

...

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:GS2") = FA_TBL
Sheet1.Range("A4:GS4") = RW_TBL
Sheet1.Range("A5:GS5") = RN_TBL
Sheet1.Range("A8:GS208") = NG_TBL
```

...

```
Sheet1.Range("A8:" & TotalCellx & "100").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range(TotalCellx & "9"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess _
    , OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    SortMethod:=xlPinYin
Sheet1.Range("C9").Select
End Function
```

I have written on Module2 (code for my form control button at Sheet2):

```
Sub Command1_Click()
Sheet1.Range("C8:GF8").Value = Sheet1.Range("C240:GF240").Value
Sheet1.Range("B7").Value = Sheet1.Range("B240").Value
r = DataUpdate()
End Sub
```

However, I get the

> "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed".

Is there any way I can call or link my command button at Sheet1 to my form control button at Sheet2?

Comment: A better option is to [avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), as you don't need to.

Comment: But it also gets and error if I remove Select.

Comment: What's the error message and on what line?

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet1

```
Public Sub ClickMe()
   MsgBox "You Clicked"
End Sub
```

In Sheet2 CommandButton Click Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Sheets("Sheet1").ClickMe
End Sub
```

Making the Routine Public makes it callable from outside the Sheet